# Create one loading scene for many levels in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have a problem with loading scene.
I've create a loading scene, and then when the it's finished, it loads another level, that's the concept, right? Now, the problem is that if I have so many scenes to load, do I have to create so many loadings scenes, too? I wonder if there are some ways so that when I load another level I still do it through the first loading scene, so I don't have to create so many loading scenes.

Here's the logic of what I've done right now: if i have 10 scenes to load, I have to create 10 loading scenes too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a variable in PlayerPref how an int for the level you need to load.
Your Loadscene got this value and load this.

In your currentScene to be unloaded:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("NextLevel",x);
```

In your LoadSceneLevel:

```
int nextlevel = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("NextLevel");
Application.LoadLevel(nextlevel);
```

Comment: [PlayerPrefs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) has not been designed to store data between Scenes (but between game sessions). Please use a static game object instead: [Tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/2d-roguelike/gamemanager)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `public static levelLoad: int;`

In your awake code do

```
nextLevelLoad = 3; //or whichever level you want to initialize.
```

Then you can do `Application.LoadLevel(nextLevelLoad);`

You can also do `Application.LoadlLevel(Application.loadedLevel + 1);` and progressively increment until `Application.levelCount - 1` is reached. (This happens because your first level is 0 and final level is  - 1 of total count.

You could use PlayerPrefs, but those are reserved for game settings and variables you wish to store.

You could also store it in a static class as opposed to static variables and persist the entire class data structure.

Many ways to skin this cat!